# Why this code won't work? Keeps returning an empty array?

Tags: javascript

It is suppose to return an array containing object in collection which holds the source attribute.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(source)) {
            arr.push(collection[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
 };
```

P.S. Just want to know, why doesn't it work. Will find the solution on my own. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add more information, what is structure of collection and what is source?

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem? Can you share a full example that triggers that behaviour?

Comment: You should throw a `debugger;` statement inside your for loop, before the if statement, and then inspect in the debugger to see what your if conditional is evaluating to.  It would appear to be evaluating to false.

Comment: Are you sure the incoming collection parameter has a length?

Comment: Are you looping through an `array` or an `object`? We need more information about the params

Comment: Oh sorry, first question on this site. Im looping through an array of objects. The goal is to extract the object which holds the source. Source is an object property.

Comment: Here's the whole thing:

function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(source)) {
            arr.push(collection[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};

console.log(whatIsInAName([{
        first: "Romeo",
        last: "Montague"
    },
    {
        first: "Mercutio",
        last: null
    },
    {
        first: "Tybalt",
        last: "Capulet"
    }
], {
    last: "Capulet"
}));

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so problem in your source object. You need to pass a property name, but you provide an another object...

if you want to fix your code, you need to iterate object keys in the source and compare it to key and value in original object (collection).